# Spring Boot, не стартует - Failed to instantiate: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

пытаюсь наладить Spring Boot проект, перевожу точнее свой MVC проект на Spring Boot, чтобы не деплоить в Томкат. Избавился от applicationContext.xml и впервые перевел все на JavaConfig смешанный с аннотациями, точнее в applicationContext.xml у меня только было получение коннекта к БД.

Было:

```
<bean id="zkSettingsHolder" class="com.uraltranscom.calculaterate.util.ZookeeperUtil.ZookeeperSettingHolder" />

<!-- дешифровка пароля -->
<bean id="decodedPassword" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetClass" value="com.uraltranscom.calculaterate.util.ZookeeperUtil.KeyMaster"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="dec"/>
    <property name="arguments">
        <list>
            <value>#{zkSettingsHolder.password}</value>
            <value>#{zkSettingsHolder.secretKey}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- устанавливаем соединение -->
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource" lazy-init="false"  destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="#{zkSettingsHolder.dataBase}"/>
    <property name="username" value="#{zkSettingsHolder.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="#{decodedPassword}"/>

</bean>

<bean class="com.uraltranscom.calculaterate.util.ConnectUtil.ConnectionDB">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Стало:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.ex.calc"})
public class AppConfig {

@Bean
@Primary
public ZookeeperSettingHolder zookeeperSettingHolder() {
    return new ZookeeperSettingHolder();
}

@Bean
public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() {
    CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    commonsMultipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10000000);
    return commonsMultipartResolver;
}

@Bean(name = "decodedPassword")
public MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean() throws Exception {
    MethodInvokingFactoryBean methodInvokingFactoryBean = new MethodInvokingFactoryBean();
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetClass(KeyMaster.class);
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setTargetMethod("dec");
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.setArguments(new String[] {zookeeperSettingHolder().getPassword(), zookeeperSettingHolder().getSecretKey()});
    methodInvokingFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
    return methodInvokingFactoryBean;
}

@Bean(destroyMethod = "close")
public DataSource dataSource() throws Exception {
    DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    dataSource.setUrl(zookeeperSettingHolder().getDataBase());
    dataSource.setUsername(zookeeperSettingHolder().getUser());
    dataSource.setPassword((String) methodInvokingFactoryBean().getObject());
    return dataSource;
}

@Bean
public ConnectionDB connectionDB() throws Exception {
    ConnectionDB connectionDB = new ConnectionDB();
    connectionDB.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return connectionDB;
}
}
```

Далее в проекте использую аннотации @Component и @Autowired

Добавил все зависимости, создал сам проект на сайте Spring.io, более точно не помню, там выбираешь нужные зависимости и тд.

Класс Application

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan({"com.ex.calc"})
public class CalcApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(CalcApplication .class, args);
}

}
```

Пытаюсь стартовать и получаю ошибку

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.ex.calc.dao.AbstractObjectFactory.<init>(AbstractObjectFactory.java:21) ~[classes/:na]
at com.ex.calc.dao.GetTotalModelDAO.<init>(GetTotalModelDAO.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490) ~[na:na]
```

При этом GetTotalModelDAO помечен аннотацией @Component и @NoArgsConstructor из библиотеки Lombok.

Если идти сверху вниз, то он ругается на мой контроллер

```
Error creating bean with name 'restControllerGetRate': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'commonLogicClass'
```

в контроллере есть объявление CommonLogicClass и он тоже помечен @Component

```
@Autowired
private CommonLogicClass commonLogicClass;
```

Далее он естественно ругается

```
Error creating bean with name 'commonLogicClass': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'getTotalModelDAO'
```

в классе CommonLogicClass есть объявление GetTotalModelDAO

```
@Autowired
private GetTotalModelDAO getTotalModelDAO;
```

И ниже ошибка

```
Error creating bean with name 'getTotalModelDAO' defined in file [C:\Users\user124\Desktop\demo\target\classes\com\ex\calc\dao\GetTotalModelDAO.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.ex.calc.dao.dao.GetTotalModelDAO]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Не понимаю, почему он получает null и как инициализировать компонент. Почитал много чего, перепробовал все, везде все так просто вроде запускается, ничего лишнего нен надо, а тут прям все, труба((

```
public class GetTotalModelDAO extends AbstractObjectFactory<TotalModel> {
```

AbstractObjectFactory:

```
@Getter
public abstract class AbstractObjectFactory<T> extends ConnectionDB implements 
ObjectFactory {
private Connection connection;

{
    try {
        connection = getDataSource().getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
public abstract T getObject(Map<String, Object> params);
}
```

Он как раз унаследует бин ConnectionDB, который есть в  AppConfig

```
@Bean
public ConnectionDB connectionDB() throws Exception {
    ConnectionDB connectionDB = new ConnectionDB();
    connectionDB.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return connectionDB;
}
```

Который из себя представляет синглтон

```
public class ConnectionDB {
private static DataSource dataSource;

private static volatile ConnectionDB instance;

public static ConnectionDB getInstance() {
    ConnectionDB localInstance = instance;
    if (localInstance == null) {
        synchronized (ConnectionDB.class) {
            localInstance = instance;
            if (localInstance == null) {
                instance = localInstance = new ConnectionDB();
            }
        }
    }
    return localInstance;
}

public static DataSource getDataSource() {
    return dataSource;
}

public static void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
    ConnectionDB.dataSource = dataSource;
}
}
```

Помогите советом пожалуйста, может я как-то неверно сконфигурировал что-то. Если нужна доп информация, говорите.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring IoC, прочитав AppConfig, создает экземпляр класса ConnectionDB который знает о DataSource:

```
@Bean
public ConnectionDB connectionDB() throws Exception {
    ConnectionDB connectionDB = new ConnectionDB();
    connectionDB.setDataSource(dataSource());
    return connectionDB;
}
```

Затем, где-то создается новый объект - экземпляр класса AbstractObjectFactory, он расширяет класс ConnectionDB, этот новый объект тоже можно называть объектом класса ConnectionDB, только этот новый объект ничего не знает про DataSource. NullPointerException возникает в инициализаторе AbstractObjectFactory, где метод getDataSource возвращает null.

Я не вижу весь код, но предположу, что можно удалить за ненадобностью AbstractObjectFactory, а в GetTotalModelDAO добавить:

```
@Autowired
private ConnectionDB connectionDb;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, как раз тока что переделал немного и понял, что косяк именно в нем. Так как теперь запустилось. А я все грешил на другой класс :)